# Transformer Insulation - High Voltage can Jump Through Ferrite Core?

Tags: high-voltage, isolation, insulation, insulation-voltage

First of all, I really searched the topic on both EE.SE and Internet but could find nothing. If this is asked before, please forgive me.

As I stated [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426654/isolated-high-voltage-amplifier-idea) earlier, I was working on an HV amplifier. We built the circuit but before testing it with the output transformer I first wanted to measure the insulation resistance of the transformer.

The guys have wound the transformer's primary and secondary across the marked pins below (i.e. primary across the red ones and the secondary across the green ones):

[image]

**Measuring method:** Descibed in the picture below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqO0Iv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

METER is a device consisting of a variac and an adjustable current threshold. If the measured current is close to the threshold then a warning lamp lights up. If the measured current exceeds the threshold then METER activates its breaker. So we rate the insulation voltage as the maximum voltage before the failure.

According to the method above with 5mA current threshold, the insulation voltage of the transformer was about 1kV which is quite low to me. Because I want it to be at least 2kV.

One of the collegues told me that it's due to the low distance between pins and the **core**. So I moved the windings start and stop pins to 3-4 and 9-10, respectively, which have higher distance to the core. After that modification, I measured the insulation voltage as 1.5kV.

I cannot explain this! How is this even possible? If it was an iron-powder core then I could explain this, because it contains "iron". But this is soft ferrite (MnZn - Manganese and Zinc) and it does not contain any "conductive" materials, doesn't it? Can high voltage really jump through the ferrite?

Comment: Probably the monster called creapage distance (creepage distance). For a [random chosen ferrite](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/ferrite_mn-zn_material_characteristics_en.pdf), the electrical
resistivity is only about 5 \$ \Omega \cdot m\$

Comment: Don't you also measure capacitive coupling as well between primary and secondary windings (or prim to core to sec, etc) when using a variac?

Comment: What does the manufacturer's datasheet state for the rated voltage for that assembly? It looks like there's only a single window in the bobbin, unless there are separate primary or secondary windows, you'll need to be very careful with the interwinding insulation or the windings will be far more of a restriction than the terminations.

Comment: Maybe you had a better flux cleaning solvent after rework? In all, this is NOT a high-voltage transformer. What is your bobbin construction?

Comment: Your test setup may be less than ideal? Not much capacitance from source to meter is needed to produce current, even at 50/60 Hz.

Comment: @PhilG In a previous question the OP said that the transformer was wound by "trainees" so I don't think there is a datasheet for the assembly. However, I think you are right about the windings.

Comment: Four days ago you told us you couldn't buy a proper transformer because you needed the amplifier the next day. Maybe you should revisit that decision.

Comment: What is your current threshold?

Comment: @PhilG as Mr. Alderson stated, there's no datasheet. And yes, the bobbin is a single-window PQ3225 with zero air gap.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I cannot put a construction diagram because I'm on mobile. But here's a description of how it's constructed: Start from pin 1, 2500 windings, stop at pin 6 (secondary) -- 3 layers of yellow polyester insulation tape -- Start from pin 7, 25 windings, stop at pin 12 (primary) -- 3 layers of yellow insulation tape. The trainees brought a hand-made winding machine and I checked that the primary winding was so nice and tight, btw.

Comment: @laptop2d 5mA. Edited the question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You are totally right, sir. I've been struggling for 2 days! Anyways, I'm looking at the bright side: This is still R&D and I'm sure I'll learn a lot of new things.

Comment: Rohat, you should know that high-voltage transformers use sectional bobbines made of high isolation plastics like Teflon, and primary-secondary windings are carefully spaced out, and leads are spaced out too, carefully. Not just some "yellow insulation tape" between layers on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ferrite has distributed particles of dielectric, conductors and magnetic particles.  Although high Mu ferrite appears to be high resistance the metallic particles coated in ceramic have very LV breakdown threshold. So it will not have good HV insulation properties.

Your primary insulation is the magnet wire.

Secondary insulation is kapton, teflon or mica or equiv tape between core and magnet wire and between primary and secondary.

Rubber ins. wire & polyurethane coating on exposed conductors will improve results after dust and humidity creep in.

With proper bobbin design, you can achieve 50kV insulation in a small form factor, but not with ferrite coated pins.  I used to buy these custom made and used 24V sine wave source for $0.30 in 100k qty with 1:1000 turns ratio. Then I used a series resonant mode.  WIth a non-saturating sine wave source, no shielding is required.  Q=X/R